# http requests working on KVM virtual machine, mysql not?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, iptables, port

I have an Ubuntu server with KVM virtual machines.

I allowed SSH in the firewall so I could access the host. Also I allowed incoming traffic that has state related, established.

**This is the full iptables setup of the host:**

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  [MYIP]               anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
DNAT       all  --  [MYIP]               [VSERVER IP]  to:192.168.122.122

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
```

The virtual server runs with Windows and has the local IP `192.168.122.122` As you can see in the `PREROUTING`, it's setup so only I can reach it at all ports.

Remote desktop works fine and I managed to connect to the server using the external IP ([VSERVER IP]). When I am connected to the server, I tried opening Internet Explorer and typed stackoverflow.com. It works, the page is displayed.

However, when I run a simple Mysql Program (using `.NET MySql.Data.dll`) which should make queries to an other server, it fails with

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x800004005): 
Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

Why is that? Http Requests to any webserver were no problem, so why is a Mysql query?

For the record, the external Mysql server is not dropping the requests (firewall temporarily disabled). It must be something in the iptables, but I don't know what.

**How can I fix this issue?**

Comment: iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 --syn -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there has been an error in the Firewall of my (external) MySQL host which I didn't know about. The MySQL port was blocked for my vServer's IP after all, so that is why the requests were not coming back and the HTTP requests were working.

The issue has been resolved.

Always double check all Firewalls! Lesson learned.